# Extract Logs from putty

Tags: java, windows, logging, cmd, putty

I have daily task to do in office. There are some log files which are created on web and app server using java applications. I have to log in to putty. Then i have to login to server. After that i have to go to certain path. And then extract some logs file which are .txt files. And then after I have to go to command prompt in windows and save the log files extracted by putty to local machine hard disk.

I want to automate the task of doing this. Is it possible to write procedure/script in putty to do this task? Please point me to resources or any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Go to the PuTTY User Manual at [this link](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/).  The section on Plink may do what you need.  I've never used this feature of PuTTY, so I don't know if it will do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with plink, I think it will capture stdout to your terminal, don't quote me on that though. I can't currently test for you as I only have a Linux machine to hand.

```
plink user@host cat /path/tofile/log.log > c:\log.txt
```

If not get a proper SFTP client which should let you do what you need.

IF you get the basic case working I'd recommend pulling the archives and extracting locally. It will be faster as text compresses well and it will be easier to control input/output filenames.